# Detect the sequence of blinking lights

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I'm looking for an example or just a starting point to achieve the following:

Using Python [openCV](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python) I want to detect the sequence of blinking lights. i.e.  on off on off = match

Is this possible and could someone start by showing me a simple example. I'm hoping from this I can learn. I learn better by examples and cannot find any to achieve sort this functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a sample video that shows how the input looks like?

Comment: @sietschie I cannot yet, but imagine a the camera looking at a large TV screen, on the TV screen it flashes... white, black, white. I want open CV to detect on, off, on for this.

Comment: If the light covers a big enough area of the image, you could use the average intensity of the image. If you got this for a sequence of images you just need to look for sudden changes in brightness which very likely means the light has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If the lightsource is very prominent in your image you can use the mean intensity of your image for detecting changes.

Here is a very simple example. I use [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEbkQE3JBPg) video for testing. 
You probably need to adjust the thresholds for your video.

If your video is not as simple as the one I used for testing you might need to make some adjustments. For example you could try to segment the light source first if there is to much distraction in the other parts of the image. Or if the intensity changes between consecutive images are not big enough, you might need to look at the changes over several images.

**Edit:**

I just saw the question was tagged with python, but my source code is C++. But I leave it for now. Maybe it helps you to get the general idea so you can port it to python yourself.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture capture(argv[1]);
    Mat frame;

    if( !capture.isOpened() )
        throw "Error when reading video";

    double lastNorm = 0.0;
    int lastCounter = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int currentState = 0;

    namedWindow( "w", 1);
    for( ; ; )
    {
        capture >> frame;
        imshow("w", frame);


        double currentNorm = norm(frame);
        double diffNorm = currentNorm - lastNorm;

        if (diffNorm > 20000 && currentState == 0)
        {
            currentState = 1;
            std::cout << "on  - was off for " << counter - lastCounter << " frames" << std::endl;
            lastCounter = counter;
        }
        if (diffNorm < -20000 && currentState == 1)
        {
            currentState = 0;
            std::cout << "off - was on  for " << counter - lastCounter << " frames" << std::endl;
            lastCounter = counter;
        }

        waitKey(20); // waits to display frame

        lastNorm = currentNorm;
        counter++;
    }
    waitKey(0); // key press to close window
    // releases and window destroy are automatic in C++ interface
}
```